# iOS redraws all ui elements after label updates

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am developing a simple game for iOS with accelerometer. When user tilts the phone, the view in center of the screen moves (I am modifying a view frame's X and Y). But when I am trying to update a label with a score, the view moves to it's initial position (where it was placed in the storyboard). I tried to use `DispatchQueue.main.async` but it didn't help me. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: this sounds like an Auto Layout related issue. Did you try to uncheck "Use Auto Layout" in your Storyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This because layout constraints are not changed , so either clear them and set a frame or add this line before you change the y origin

```
self.someView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = true
```

Comment: This works, but after I added this line my view spawns closer to the left side of the screen

Comment: Sorry, that was because I called this line in viewDidLoad. Everything works fine after I moved it to viewDidAppear